# map function if a predicate holds

Tags: dictionary, haskell, filter, functional-programming

I feel like this should be fairly obvious, or easy, but I just can't get it. What I want to do is apply a function to a list (using `map`) but only if a condition is held. Imagine you only wanted to divide the numbers which were even:

```
map (`div` 2) (even) [1,2,3,4]
```

And that would give out `[1,1,3,2]` since only the even numbers would have the function applied to them. Obviously this doesn't work, but is there a way to make this work without having to write a separate function that you can give to `map`? `filter` is almost there, except I also want to keep the elements which the condition doesn't hold for, and just not apply the function to them.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you don't want to define separate function, then use lambda.

```
map (\x -> if (even x) then (x `div` 2) else x) [1,2,3,4]
```

Or instead of a map, list comprehension, bit more readable I think.

```
[if (even x) then (x `div` 2) else x | x <- [1,2,3,4]]
```

Comment: @PPiotrLegnica: In this case, list comprehension might be bad for performance, because it translate to `concatMap` which causes the creation of a superfluous layer of lists.

Comment: @FUZxxl: Run `ghc -ddump-simpl`, you'll see that no intermediary lists are created.  The default [rewrite rules](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/users_guide/rewrite-rules.html) and other optimization passes are smarter than that.

Comment: Yes. I forgot about that. GHC is damned smart, some times even so smart to remove the roadblocks I set to block his optimization... :)

Answer (score 9):

```
mapIf p f = map (\x -> if p x then f x else x)
```

Comment: Note that this can be made into a more general utility for `Functor` s, not just lists, if you change `map` to `fmap` in the above.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the answer of PiotrLegnica: Often, it's easier to read if you declare a helper function instead of using a lambda. Consider this:

```
map helper [1..4] where
  helper x | even x    = x `div` 2
           | otherwise = x
```

(`[1..4]` is sugar for `[1,2,3,4]`)

If you want to remove all the other elements instead, consider using `filter`. `filter` removes all elements that don't satisfy the predicate:

```
filter even [1..4] -> [2,4]
```

So you can build a pipe of `map`and filter than or use list-comprehension instead:

```
map (`div` 2) $ filter even [1..4]
[x `div` 2 | x <- [1..4], even x]
```

Choose whatever you like best.

Answer (score 2):

Make your own helper function maker:

```
ifP pred f x = 
    if pred x then f x
    else x

custom_f = ifP even f
map custom_f [..]
```

(caveat: I don't have access to a compiler right now. I guess this works OK...)

Comment: Personally I'd call this `whenP`, since `if` makes me think there should be an `else` case as well, but I like this solution.

Answer (score 1):

I like the other, more general solutions, but in your very special case you can get away with

```
map (\x -> x `div` (2 - x `mod` 2)) [1..4]
```

Answer (score 0):

Mostly a rip off of existing answers, but according to my biased definition of "readable" (I like guards more than ifs, and `where` more than `let`):

```
mapIf p f = map f'
    where f' x | p x = f x | otherwise = x
```

ghci says it probably works

```
ghci> let mapIf p f = map f' where f' x | p x = f x | otherwise = x
ghci> mapIf even (+1) [1..10]
[1,3,3,5,5,7,7,9,9,11]
```